# objective-c iterate though an Array of subclass types and call class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Say that I have a base class with a class method:

> @interface base : NSObject
>
> +(id)method;
>
> @end

And I have 10 derived classes:from derived1 to derived10, each of them overwrite the method:

```
@interface derived1 : base 
@end
```

now that's the problem, I have an array like this:

> NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[derived1 class],[derived2
>   class].......[derived10 class]];

now I want to iterate through this array and call each element's method,how to?

PS: I need to perform the method one by one in an foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Iterate like you would normally
2. Get the object's class
3. Call the method on that

   ```
   for (id object in objects) {
       [[object class] method];
   }
   ```

### Edit

The above is if you have concrete instances (@Alladinian :) cheers) otherwise if your example code is literal and you are in fact putting the classes in the array you just use

```
for (id object in objects) {
   [object method];
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Doesn't this solution require that he got concrete instances of the involved classes in order to add/iterate the objects ?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have an array like the one you posted:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[derived1 class],[derived2 class]..[derived10 class]];

[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(method)];
```

**EDIT:**
OP edited the question and said that he needs to iterate and execute one by one. So go with Paul's answer, it's really what you need :)

Comment: sorry buddy, I want' to perform the method one by one by and foreach loop. I'll edit my post

Comment: @user465191 Ok I've edited the answer. I'm not deleting it since it may be useful to somebody else, but you should go with Paul's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look up NSArray methods. makeObjectsPerformSelector or makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject: or enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: or enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock: all do that. Plus you could simply iterate with a for and call the method on each object.